# How do I use javascript to simulate a mouse click (in Google Maps)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

http://geodit.com:8000/test

Here, I have a simple Google Local Search API and Google Maps code.

How do I make it so that when I click the title of a search result, I simulate the clicking of the address? My objective is to make the pop up box appear on the map by clicking the title.  I binded it to this:

```
$(".gs-title").click(function(){

    //SIMULATE MOUSE CLICK of the address HERE
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".gs-address").click(); // this doesn't work!!

    alert("the title was clicked!!"); //this works fine.
    return false; //this also works fine. The hyperlink gets disabled because I returned false.

});
```

I want to be able to click the title, NOT open the link. And then, pop up the box on the map. In other words, I want to treat the the result as a whole.

Comment: Are you sure that `$(this).parent().parent().find(".gs-address")` is actually finding what you think it's finding?

Comment: I do see it opening the popup fine when I click the results. But I do also see the pop up window opening. If I just click the address area and not the title then it does what you want. What am I missing?

Comment: I want to be able to click the title, NOT open the link. And then, pop up the box on the map. In other words, I want to treat the the result as a whole.

Comment: When I add the return false, the link does not open up. However, there is no pop up anymore.  Disregard my previous code. What can I add to the current script so that when the title is clicked, the pop up appears, but the new tab does NOT come up?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I removed the A tags manually.

```
// Returns the HTML we display for a result before it has been "saved"
    LocalResult.prototype.html = function() {
      var me = this;
      var container = document.createElement("div");
      container.className = "unselected";
      container.appendChild(me.result_.html.cloneNode(true));
      $(container).find('a').replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); });

      return container;
    }
```

Comment: Nice, I was think to suggest the whole rewrite of LocalResult.prototype.html, but it's not so simple to do :D Your solution is really nasty :> eheheh

Answer (score 0):

The Html code is:

```
    <div class="gs-title"><a target="_blank" class="gs-title" href="http://www.google.com/maps/place?source=uds&amp;q=pizza&amp;cid=12855512876323852687">California <b>Pizza</b> Kitchen</a></div>

    <div class="gs-address">...
```

so I think right path coul'd be:

```
$("a.gs-title").click(function(){

 $(this).parent().siblings('.gs-address').click();return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried that. But for some reason the pop up info is not showing up?

Comment: The .click is not really activating the pop up info.